# Javascript get data totals into list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this data:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "name here",
    "thsub": {
        "637": {
            "id": "637",
            "name": "Sub 1",
            "stats": {
                "items": 5,
            },
            "ons": null
        },
        "638": {
            "id": "638",
            "name": "Sub 2",
            "stats": {
                "items": 10,
            },
            "ons": null
        }
    },
    "ph": 10,
}
```

Here's is the code:

```
mydata = [mydata];

var chList=[];
var thList=[];
var thCount=[];

for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {

    var obj = mydata[i];
    var cl = obj.name;
    if (obj.thsub != null) {
        chList.push(cl);
    }

    if(obj.thsub) {
        if (i < 10) {

            var nme = Object.keys(obj.thsub).map( function(key){
                var item = obj.thsub[key];
                return item.name;

            });

            thCount.push(numberofitems);

            thList = thList.concat(nme);
            thCount = thCount.concat(Array(nme.length).fill(nme.length));

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in the thCount ... what I need to do is to count each "items" on obj.thsub.638 or other ...stats.items and put the totals into thCount like I've got in thList.

So the desired result woule be 5 and 10  in other words: [5, 10] in this case.

thCount would be [5, 10]

How can I do this?

Comment: not very sure of the question asked, are you looking for "stats": {
                "items": 5,
            } value for each of your thsub ?

Comment: Your `mydata` is an object. It does not have a `length`.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I just want to count the item's into an array all the rest works fine

Comment: Tried: console.log(mydata[0].thsub[i].stats.items); but I get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should access the json objects using key value, index is for arrays. below code just does the thcount for you

```
        var data = {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "name here",
        "thsub": {
            "637": {
                "id": "637",
                "name": "Sub 1",
                "stats": {
                    "items": 5,
                },
                "ons": null
            },
            "638": {
                "id": "638",
                "name": "Sub 2",
                "stats": {
                    "items": 10,
                },
                "ons": null
            }
        },
        "ph": 10,
    };
    var thCount = [];
    for(key in data.thsub ){
      if(data.thsub[key].stats){
       thCount.push(data.thsub[key].stats.items);
      }
    }
    console.log(thCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values` gives you the list of values of a given object and then you can map your result in an array. in ES5:

```
var arr = Object.values(mydata.thsub).map(function(item) {
    return item.stats.items
});
```

in ES6:

```
const list = Object.values(mydata.thsub).map(item => item.stats.items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative recursive approach for getting the wanted values.

```js
function getValues(object, key) {

    function iter(o) {
        if (key in o) {
            result.push(o[key]);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                iter(o[k]);
            }
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object);
    return result;
}

var data = { id: "123", name: "name here", thsub: { 637: { id: "637", name: "Sub 1", stats: { items: 5, }, ons: null }, 638: { id: "638", name: "Sub 2", stats: { items: 10, }, ons: null } }, ph: 10, };
  
console.log(getValues(data, 'items'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```